# how to configure and install a standby master in greenplum?

Tags: greenplum

Ive installed a single node greenplum db with 2 segment hosts , inside them residing 2 primary and mirror segments , and i want to configure a standby master , can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple.

```
gpinitstandby -s smdw -a
```

Note: If you are using one of the cloud Marketplaces that deploys Greenplum for you, the standby master runs on the first segment host.  The overhead of running the standby master is pretty small so it doesn't impact performance.  The cloud Marketplaces also have self-healing so if that nodes fails, it is replaced and all services are automatically restored.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon said, this is fairly straightforward.  Here is a link to the documentation:  https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/5170/utility_guide/admin_utilities/gpinitstandby.html

If you have follow up questions, post them here.